# McCabe's cyclomatic complexity

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

To calculate the cyclomatic complexity of a code, I drew a control flow chart consisting of nodes and edges which helped me to calculate V (G) = E - N + 2
In my case E = 15 and N = 11. Resulting in a cyclomativ complexity of 6.

Now to confirm my answer I would like some help on finding linearly independent paths for the code blow:

```
int maxValue = m[0][0];         
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)         
{                       
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)          
   {                        
      if ( m[i][j] > maxValue )         
      {                     
         maxValue = m[i][j];            
      }                     
   }                        
}                   
cout << maxValue << endl;           
int sum = 0;                    
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)         
{                       
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)          
   {                        
      sum = sum + m[i][j];          
   }                        
}                           
cout << sum << endl;
```

This should equal the result for my V (G), otherwise my calculation is wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

McCabe's cyclomatic complexity gives an upper bound. Consider the following:

```
void func (const bool do_special) {
    if (do_special) {
        do_something_special_at_the_start();
    }

    always_do_this_stuff_in_the_middle();

    if (do_special) {
        do_something_special_at_the_end();
}
```

From a graph theory perspective, this has a cyclomatic complexity of three. However, since `do_special` is constant, there are only two independent paths through the code. The graph theory model doesn't know that some paths are impossible. The number of *possible* paths through the graph is sometimes less than the cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: Your cyclomatic complexity of 6 is correct. How one counts nodes and edges varies (I count 16 nodes, 20 edges), but the cyclomatic complexity will be always be 6 if the counting is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Hammen,
A very good example for stating that this metric gives the upper bound. But somehow, you might have missed a point about the complexity of this example while giving it as three. Since you have shown do_something_...(), they are function calls. Hence in this case P = 3 and so the Cyclomatic complexity will be given by V(G) = E - N - 2*P, also E and N should include the edges and nodes of the called functions too. I think instead, the example can be written as:

```
void func (const bool do_special) {

   if (do_special) {
      /* do something at start */
   }
   :
   /* do something at middle */
   :
   if (do_speical) {
      /* do something at end */
   }
}
```

Hope you agree!