# Cyclomatic Complexity in piece of code with multiple exit points

Tags: java, return, complexity-theory, cyclomatic-complexity

I have this method that validates a password:

```
/**
 * Checks if the given password is valid.
 * 
 * @param password The password to validate.
 * @return {@code true} if the password is valid, {@code false} otherwise.
 */
public static boolean validatePassword(String password) {
    int len = password.length();
    if (len < 8 || len > 20)
        return false;
    boolean hasLetters = false;
    boolean hasDigits = false;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
            return false;
        hasDigits = hasDigits || Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i));
        hasLetters = hasLetters || Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i));
    }
    return hasDigits && hasLetters;
}
```

Let's focus on the cyclomatic complexity number: what is its value?

[Metrics 1.3.6](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) says it's 7, but I cannot really find seven independent paths: I only find 5! And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) didn't help out much—how am I suppose to use this formula `π - s + 2`?

I have 2 `if`'s, 1 `for` and 3 exit points but I'm stuck: do I have to count the entry point? Should I count twice the first `if` since it has two conditions?

**EDIT:**

Ok, now I found out that Cyclomatic Number is 7. This means that there are 7 independent paths and so I should be able to find 7 different test cases if I would to cover 100% of code, am I right?

Well, I still cannot found the last one!
I found these:

1. Valid: asdf1234
2. Too short: asdf123
3. Too long: asdfsgihzasweruihioruldhgobaihgfuiosbhrbgtadfhsdrhuorhguozr
4. Invalid character: asdf*123
5. All-digit: 12345678
6. No-digits: asdfghjk
7. wtf???

Comment: Look at the normalized code in my answer. After accounting for short-circuiting of `||` and `&&` you have 7 branching statements

Comment: The 7th branch is when the `for` loop terminates. One path goes in the for loop, another goes out. You never have the case of the `for` loop not running in your code because you check for `len < 8` at the start of your function, but simple automated code analysis won't reflect that.

Comment: @Claudiu: I thought it could be that but I wasn't sure... my doubt is: why should the `for` count twice, where `if`'s and everything else counts just for once? Even `if` statement has two way but increment ccn only by one and so should do the `for` as well. :|

Comment: I don't think you will actually have 7 different test cases, because some of your decision points are actually checking the same thing: if `!isLetterOrDigit` is true then we know either `isDigit` or `isLetter` will be true.

Comment: @tmh: the `for` doesn't count twice. You have six `if` statements and one `loop`.

Comment: @matts: thanks! That's it! How silly I was!

Comment: "how am I suppose to use this formula π - s + 2" ==> That can be done when you make the control flow graph of your code where π is the number of nodes , s the number of edges. You can find many tools that can generate the graph flow automatically for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trick is that the logical operators are counted.

Based off of your Metrics link (http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) under the McCabe Cyclomatic Complexity section:

1 Initial flow

3 decision points (if,for,if)

3 conditional logic operators (||,||,||)

total: 7

Comment: btw, logical operators are counted as branches because they have [short-circuit behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  e.g., when the expression on the left side of the `||` operator evaluates to `true`, the right side is not executed.

Comment: I guess your right, but I wonder... is this correct? So what's the real cyclomatic number of that piece of code? Is Metrics right? The point of all of this is the cover all possible paths for testing. EDIT: thinking it twice, I found out that metrics is right; I did not considered two test cases: all-numeric password and a password without any digit. Btw I think that the last && does not increment ccn: you didn't count the main flow :)

Comment: You are correct. Answer edited to show this. It seems like there are many ways to count that generally end up being the same total: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365912/mccabes-cyclomatic-complexity

Comment: I edited my answer, can you please give a look? :) Maybe you can help me :)

Comment: It is possible that two paths could be combined even though the complexity gives a certain number. For example, if you had `if (SOME_CONSTANT) {}` that would be a decision point, but it would only flow through one of the two branches because it is based on a constant. Similarly, if you can't find a 7th test case, it may be because it is already duplicated in a previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main thing here is that conditionals do short-circuiting, which is a form of control flow. What helps is to re-write the code to make that explicit. This sort of normalization is common when doing program analysis. Some ad-hoc normalization (not formal and a machine wouldn't generate this, but it gets the point across) would make your code look like the following:

```
public static boolean validatePassword(String password) {
    int len = password.length();

    //evaluate 'len < 8 || len > 20'
    bool cond1 = len < 8;
    if (!cond1) cond1 = len > 20;
    //do the if test
    if (cond1)
        return false;

    boolean hasLetters = false;
    boolean hasDigits = false;
    //for loops are equivalent to while loops
    int i = 0;
    while(i < len) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
            return false;

        //evaluate 'hasDigits || Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))'
        bool hasDigitsVal = hasDigits;
        if (!hasDigitsVal) hasDigitsVal = Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i));
        //hasDigits = ...
        hasDigits = hasDigitsVal

        //evaluate 'hasLetters || Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i))'
        bool hasLettersVal = hasLetters;
        if (!hasLettersVal) hasLettersVal = Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i));
        //hasLetters = ...
        hasLetters = hasLettersVal;

        i++;
    }

    //evaluate 'hasDigits && hasLetters'
    bool cond2 = hasDigits;
    if (cond2) cond2 = hasLetters;
    //return ...
    return cond2;
}
```

Notice how the `||` and `&&` operators essentially just add `if` statements to the code. Also notice that you now have 6 `if` statements and one `while` loop! Maybe that is the 7 you were looking for?

---

About multiple exit points, that's a red herring. Consider each function as having one exit node, the end of the function. If you have multiple `return` statements, each `return` statement would draw an edge to that exit node.

```
void foo() {
    if (cond1) return a;
    if (cond2) return b;
    return c;
}
```

The graph would look like this, where `-----val----> EXIT` means exiting the function with a value of `val`:

```
START -> cond1 ------------------------a------------> EXIT
           |                                            |
         cond2 ------------------------b----------------+
           |                                            |
         return -----------------------c----------------|
```

If you re-write the code, then you just basically add another "pre-return" node that then goes to the exit node:

```
void foo() {
    int val;
    if (cond1) {
        val= a;
    }
    else {
        if (cond2) {
            val= b;
        }
        else {
            val= c;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
START -> cond1 ---> val=a --------------------------> return ----val----> EXIT
           |                                            |
         cond2 ---> val=b ------------------------------+
           |                                            |
           + -----> val=c ------------------------------+
```

It's still as complex, and the code is just uglier.

Comment: "I wouldn't say it has multiple exit points" what do you mean by that? I used to thing that everytime you return you add an exit point (e.g. `if (somecondition) return;`)

Comment: @tmh: i updated my answer to show what I mean. thinking about multiple `return` statements is a red herring IMO

Answer (score 0):

As nicely explained [here](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/current/McCabe_Cyclomatic_Complexity) :

> Cyclomatic Complexity = ( 2 + ifs + loops +cases - return ) where:
>
> ```
> * ifs is the number of IF operators in the function,
> * loops is the number of loops in the function,
> * cases is the number of switch branches in the function (without default), and
> * return is the number of return operators in the function.
> ```

As already mentioned, logical conditions are also calculated.

For example `if (len < 8 || len > 20)` counts as 3 conditions :

1. `if`
2. `len<8`
3. `len > 20`

That means, that your code has complexity of `2 + 8 - 3 = 7`, where :

- 2 - it is always there (see formula up there)
- 8 - number of branches
- 3 - number of returns