# What will happen if we have multiple start and stop in cyclometric graph

Tags: testing, cyclomatic-complexity

recently i had a question that was so confusing.What would happen if a control flow graph consists of multiple start and/or stop nodes?

Comment: You have Java tagged to your question - could you explain the connection please?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake.corrected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cyclomatic Complexity for multiple return statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782629/cyclomatic-complexity-for-multiple-return-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Control Flow Graphs can contain multiple start and end nodes.But it will restrict using McCabe's theory to calculate Cyclomatic Complexity.Only the structured programs with one entry point and a exit point will satisfy the equation